# i want to hide all json response data from the browser

Tags: php, json

[image]

this is my response . I want that no body can see this response how can i solve this problem .please tell me some thing about it..

Comment: simply don't send the data to the client which you wan't to hide. do you have any reason that you have to send it ?

Comment: actually i want to send all data but it should not be seen in web browser like this image . If i put this URL in browser it should be blank but it should have data. for security reason.

Comment: it should be run on rest client..

Comment: please tell me some thing about it.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible. you should do the calculation in the server side if you want the data to be hidden for client.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should encode server side as well as client side..i.e your server should return an encoded data whose secret key to decode is available only on your client side..